# Array only show last record

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Currently I'm using codeigniter and below are my formatted array.

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "AAAA"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "ABCDDE"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "1234456"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "AAAA"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "ABCDDE"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "1234456"
}
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "AAAA"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "ABCDDE"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [3]=>
  string(7) "1234456"
}
```

but when it load into the view, the array only show last of records. How to put all array on the text area box on the view, because data only show last records.

Controller

```
for ($i=0;$i<count($input);$i++) {

            $loopvar = explode(',',$input[$i]);

$data['abc'] = $loopvar;
$this->load->view('content', $data, FALSE);
}
```

View

```
<textarea style="width:99%;" rows="1000" name='soapresult'><?php echo var_dump($abc); ?>
            </textarea></td>
```

Comment: What does `$msisdn` in your view have to do with the previous PHP-code? How are they connected? And do you mean to load that view on each iteration?

Comment: add complete controller code...

Comment: Btw, doesn't `$this->load->view()` only accept three parameters? Like: `$this->load->view('the-view', ['some data'], $returnInsteadOfRender = true)`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : oops i got wrong var, should $abc, but still doesn;t fix the issue, and i've edit the controller, PF above

Comment: your need to take `$this->load->view('content', $data, FALSE);` out of the for loop

Comment: Is this code a copy/paste from the real code or did you rewrite it here? If it's a rewrite, update the question with a copy/paste from your _real_ code.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : I did it, but still show last record of array

Comment: @MagnusEriksson : i think i got last array because of same index of array, for that code, how to make the index different ?